# don´t know how to translate a prolog rule to lisp

Tags: lisp

Hi I am working in a simple expert system in Prolog, based on facts and rules.

The problem that I have is that I need to translate the prolog code into Lisp. I already did the facts but don´t know how to do the rules. How could I translate this line:

gimnosperms(Y):-plants(Y),with_seeds(Y).

Answer (score 3):

Direct translation between the two languages is almost impossibile, since they have a very different semantics.

In a lisp language you define *functions*, that is “machines” that, given a certain input, produce a certain output.

In Prolog you define *relations*, through rules and facts, that can have different uses:

1. as predicates, when you pass to them one or more constant values, to see if they satisfy the condition specified (for instance, you can pass a constant to gimnosperms, and get an answer yes/no if the constant is both a plant and has seed), or if they belongs to the set of facts.
2. as generators, in which you pass a “variable” and all the costants of the domain (described in the facts), that satisfy the condition are generated, one after the other, interactively, or all together,
3. as general solver for a certain problem, in which only part of input is a given data (constant), while other is a variable that is assigned to the constants that cause the satisfaction of all the conditions (and the role of input and output can be exchanged each time).

And this without considering the Prolog “functions”, that correspond to data structures in lisp, and require a pattern-matching mechanism to be correctly implemented, neither the non-determinism, which is inherent to the Prolog semantics.

So, first of all, each rule should correspond to different functions. For instance, while 1 is very easily solved, through the definition of a predicate (examples are in Common Lisp):

```
(defun is-gimnosperms (y)
  (and (is-plants y) (is-with_seeds y)))
```

and it is relatively easy to write a generator (2), for instance to produce all gimnosperms you could write:

```
(defun all-gimnosperms ()
  (loop for y in (all-plants) when (is-with-seeds y) collect y))
```

given the following facts and rules:

```
(defun all-plants () '(oak cypress pine ginkgo ...))

(defun all-with-seeds () '(ginkgo ...))

(defun is-with-seeds (y) (member y (all-with-seeds)))
```

but in general it is much more complex to implement a general solver for a certain problem (this is not in your example, since the rule has only one parameter).

Actually, the only reasonable approach to solve this problem is to define a general unifier, and use that to implement a Prolog interpreter! And if you google about “prolog in lisp”, you can find different solutions, for instance that in the Chapter 24 of the excellent Paul Graham book ["On Lisp"](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html), available [also on line](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html).

**Final note**

Of course nothing prevent a labourious implementation, function by function, of the different roles of a Prolog rule. For instance, you could assume that a rule is implemented through a function that gets in input something which can be either `(CONSTANT x)`, where `x` is a constant, and `(VARIABLE x)` where `x` is a symbol which is the name of a special (global) variable. In the first case the function will check if `x` satisfy the rule, in the second one it will assign to the variable all the values defined in the fact, or satisfying the condition. But this “manual” approach of course is infeasible: when you have *n* parameters you should check and implement 2<sup>*n*</sup> different cases!